# Can the opacity of a background image of a label be changed programmatically without changing the opacity of the text? (Swift)

Tags: swift, uiimage, uicolor

I have a label that has a background image that's being set programmatically but I can't quite figure out how (or if it's possible) to customize that image's opacity without affecting the label. This is my label:

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"ImageName")!)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `withAlphaComponent()` **Swift 3** to set the image's opacity

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:"myImage")!).withAlphaComponent(0.3)
```

Comment: Yes Swift 3 sorry

Comment: Did you mean `colorWithAlphaComponent` because I just tried that and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You can try also this:

```
myLabel.backgroundColor =UIColor(patternImage:UIImage(named:"myImage")!).colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)
```